# App usando canvas não emula no Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-activity, canvas, instanciar-objeto, emulador

Fiz um app no Android Studio, conforme códigos abaixo, porém, ao emular dentro de um emulador do próprio Android Studio, não executa. Parece que há algum problema no instaciamento da Activity, mas o manifest parece tá certo, assim como o onCreate na classe java. Aí eu não entendo o que acontece! Erro com algum pacote? Algum código mal instanciado? Não sei!

**Erro na tela Run:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: br.com.dimtecarte.www.jumper, PID: 5836
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{br.com.dimtecarte.www.jumper/br.com.dimtecarte.www.jumper.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:87)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:81)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.getResources(AppCompatActivity.java:577)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3778)
        at android.view.SurfaceView.<init>(SurfaceView.java:184)
        at br.com.dimtecarte.www.jumper.Game.<init>(Game.java:15)
        at br.com.dimtecarte.www.jumper.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:10)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**game.java:**

```
package br.com.dimtecarte.www.jumper;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;//Esse SurfaceView é para criar uma tela onde calcularemos a posição de cada objeto.


public class Game extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{
    private final SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder(); //Nos dá acesso ao canvas, permitindo a edição de cada pixel nos cenários.
    private Passaro passaro;

    public Game(Context context){
        super(context);
        inicializaElementos();
    }

    public boolean isRunning = true;  //Dirá se o app está rodando.

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (isRunning){ //Se verdadeiro, executará o bloco abaixo repetidadamente.
            if(!holder.getSurface().isValid()) continue;      //Se o SurfaceHolder estiver pronto para desenhar, pode continuar.
            Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            passaro.desenhaNo(canvas);
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas); //Depois que terminar de desenhar a tela, ela substituirá a tela antiga.
        }
    }

    public void cancela(){   //Vai cancelar a execução do app para para o while acima. Isto é importante para não sobrecarregar o uso do aparelho.
        this.isRunning=false;
    }

    public void inicia(){    //Vai retomar a execução do app. O while voltará a ser executado.
        this.isRunning=true;
    }

    public void inicializaElementos(){
        this.passaro = new Passaro();
    }

    public  class Passaro{
        private final Paint vermelho = Cores.getCorDoPassaro();  //Obtendo a cor.
        private static final int X = 100;
        private static final int RAIO = 50;
        private final int altura;

        public Passaro(){
            this.altura=100;
        }

        public void desenhaNo(Canvas canvas){
            canvas.drawCircle(X, altura, RAIO,vermelho);  //Vai desenhar um círculo vermelho.
        }
    }
    public static class Cores{
        public static Paint getCorDoPassaro() {
            Paint vermelho = new Paint();
            vermelho.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
            return vermelho;
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package br.com.dimtecarte.www.jumper;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Game game = new Game(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        FrameLayout container = findViewById(R.id.container);
        container.addView(game);
    }
    //-------------------------------MÉTODOS DO CICLO DE VIDA DA ACTIVITY--------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    protected void onPause(){ //Quando o app for pausado, vai determinar o que será feito.
        super.onPause();
        game.cancela();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume(){ //Quando o app entrar em primeiro plano novamente, vai determinar o que acontecerá.
        super.onResume();
        game.inicia();
        new Thread(game).start();
    }}
```

**manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                package="br.com.dimtecarte.www.jumper">

    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Design.NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Logcat:**

12-30 11:18:22.961 1693-1693/system_process E/LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/gatekeeper.password.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

12-30 11:18:22.961 1693-1693/system_process E/LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/password.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

12-30 11:18:22.961 1693-1693/system_process E/LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/gatekeeper.pattern.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

12-30 11:18:22.962 1693-1693/system_process E/LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/gatekeeper.gesture.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

12-30 11:18:22.963 1693-1693/system_process E/LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/gesture.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)